# AJAX not submiting

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I have a laravel project where admin can change user data via form. I want this form to be submitted by ajax. But it doesn't get submited.

I have a form:

```
<form id="userData{{$loop->iteration}}" method="POST">
@csrf
<!--some inputs-->
</form>

<button id="changeUserData{{$loop->iteration}}" data-id="#userData{{$loop->iteration}}">Save</button>
```

JS:

```
$("#changeUserData{{$loop->iteration}}").click(function (e) {
  var ele = $(this);
  var formId = ele.attr("data-id");
  console.log(formId);
  $(formId).submit(function (e){
    console.log("test2");
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: '{{url('changeUserData')}}',
      method: "PATCH",
      data: $(formId).serialize(),
      success: function(){
        console.log("test");
      }
    })
  })
});
```

When I press the button the first console.log gets fired but nothing else. I checked if formId matches the form id and it does so I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: `submit` don't has any callback. If you add a callback, you are registering the submit event, you are not actually submitting the form. Check jQuery documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is [`.submit()`](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) with `handler` argument does not submit the form itself. It just binds an event handler to the form's `submit` event.

You may just remove that bind and it should work:

```js
$("#changeUserData{{$loop->iteration}}").click(function (e) {
    var ele = $(this);
    var formId = ele.attr("data-id");
    console.log(formId);

    $.ajax({
        url: '{{url('changeUserData')}}',
        method: "PATCH",
        data: $(formId).serialize(),
        success: function(){
          console.log("test");
        }
    })
})
```